# (PA)^2 + (PB)^2 +(PC)^2 + (PD)^2 is equal to?

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

A circle is inscribed into the rhombus ABCD with one angle 60. The distance from the centre of the circle to the narest vertex is equal to 1. If P is any point of the circle ,then $$(PA)^2 + (PB)^2 +(PC)^2 + (PD)^2$$ is equal to?

Comment: Fix your title please

Comment: http://goo.gl/8WZI2X

Comment: answer given is 11 but he is getting 11/3

Comment: The solution on that link is wrong. The answer I got is $8+2\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @mathslover That answer is very close, it just make the mistake $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} > 1$. You can get the right answer by scaling the geometric figure by $\sqrt{3}$.